# Mule: Accessing counter variable from component inside foreach

Tags: foreach, mule, mule-studio

I have a foreach element in my flow, which has a variable named "counter" set. Inside the foreach, I have a component, and I'm trying to get access to the "counter" variable from within the component. What is the proper way to get a hold of this variable from inside the component? Does it require adding a parameter to the method? I already have a parameter to take in the payload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any variable from the mule flow can be accessed inside a Component by using the

```
muleMessage.getInvocationProperty("counter");
```

muleMessage can be obtained from `MuleEventContext` of the `onCall(MuleEventContext arg0)` method. Assuming that you have implemented `Callable` interface of mule.

If not, try getting the message from   `org.mule.RequestContext.getEvent().getMessage()`
This is RequestContext is deprecated as of now.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If we set the counter value in a property, we can get that property in inbound properties of message inside the component.
some thing like this

```
 <set-variable variableName="counter" value="10" />
 <set-property propertyName="testout" value="#[counter]" doc:name="Property" />
```

Thanks-